# undefined reference to `glib_major_version'

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, gcc

Can you please tell me how can I resolve this 'undefined reference' error when linking on Ubuntu 10.10

> conftest.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `glib_major_version'
>
> conftest.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `glib_minor_version'
>
> conftest.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `glib_micro_version'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have added 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to my .bashrc.

> $ ls -la libgl*.*
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 2010-12-17 18:29 libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.2600.0
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 842208 2010-09-27 16:16 libglib-2.0.so.0.2600.0
>
> /lib $ pwd
>
> /lib

But that does not solve the problem.  What should I do?

Comment: Did you add `-lglib` to your linker options, e.g. `gcc -lglib` or `ld -lglib` or `LDFLAGS=-lglib`?

Comment: Is this your own code, or someone else's?  Does it have a `./configure` script?  You need to show us what leads up to the error, e.g. what command you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What command are you running to compile it?**

Are there any other errors leading up to this error?

---

I have the same version of the file as you, and it has those symbols.

```
$ ls -l libglib*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 2010-12-05 06:03 libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.2600.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 842208 2010-09-28 09:16 libglib-2.0.so.0.2600.0
$ nm -D libglib-2.0.so.0.2600.0 | grep version
00073730 T glib_check_version
000c849c R glib_major_version
000c84a4 R glib_micro_version
000c84a0 R glib_minor_version
```

Are you compiling your own program?  Perhaps you just need to tell the linker to link in `glib` by adding the `-lglib-2.0` option.

If you are running
`gcc -o conftest conftest.c`, you should do
`gcc -o conftest -lglib-2.0 conftest.c` instead.

Or you can add `-lglib-2.0` to `LDFLAGS`.

---

Are you compiling someone else's program?  It might be using `pkgconfig`.  There might be some stuff in `/usr/local` that is confusing things.

Did you install any other programs or libraries yourself?  Perhaps something that installed itself in `/usr/local/lib`?

What does `cat /usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib*` say?
What does `cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glib*` say?

You might need to change the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/usr/local/lib`, or perhaps change `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, or add some options to `./configure`.

The answer depends on what you are doing.